# AJAX inserting data for username-check, results in duplicated div elements and no data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The code below is supposed to check whether a username has already been taken before the form has been submitted. However once a name is typed in to the input, `div` elements are repeated and there is no output of data. Can anybody please assist with this problem using AJAX?

php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['check_username'])) {
    $user_login_name = $_POST['check_username'];

    $sql = "SELECT user_login_name FROM users;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if (!empty($user_login_name)) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if (strpos($row, $user_login_name) != false) {
                echo $row;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Database empty!";
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="register">
            <div class="band_1">
                <div class="box">
                    <form action="../server/register.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="input_table">                           
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><h1>Register to LIMS</h1></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="user_first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="user_last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="user_phone" placeholder="Enter Contact Number"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="user_login_name" placeholder="Select a Username"><p id="test"></p></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="Select a Password"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="password" name="user_password_2" placeholder="Repeat Password"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" name="user_register" class="button_1">Register</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button_3">Cancel</button>              
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[name=user_login_name]").keyup(function(){
        var user_login_name = $("input[name=user_login_name]").val();
        $.post("../server/register.php", {
            check_username: user_login_name
        }, function(data, status) {
            $("#test").html(data);
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You have an possibly unrelated bug in your PHP logic using `strpos()`. You need to use `!==` instead of `!=` because that function can return 0 (which is "falsy") if the string match starts at the first character. See more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: I just changed that, thanks, but did not resolve my problem. It pastes the entire `<html>` tag data in the `#test` id.

Comment: May i ask, are the PHP code and HTML code in the same file?

Comment: No they are not, i try linking all the different languages in different files.

Comment: It seems that the php code has to be inside its own file, since I had it in a file with other php code. Can anyone give a reason as to why separating the php code was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, just improve php:

1) you need to check on emptiness user's input, 2) and select only matched, 3) and call `die` finally :

```
if (!empty($_POST['check_username'])) {
    $user_login_name = $_POST['check_username'];

    $sql = "SELECT user_login_name FROM users where user_login_name like '%$user_login_name%';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            echo "$row<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Database empty!";
    }

    die;
}
```

UPDATE. Also this would better to call: `$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` - to prevent retrieving extra data twice.

Comment: You realize that you're leaving them open to SQL injection with the added `WHERE` clause. Have you not heard of that and prepared statements?

Comment: Yes, you are right - just forgot about injection. Of course this is must have to protect mysql query, thanks. (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). My common idea was around improvement "select-query": no need to fetch all users from db and check each one in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

There's your php code with a better way to check if an user exists in DB.
Just check in the query if user exists and number, you don't need to check it with php.

```
if(isset($_POST['check_username'])){
    $user_login_name=$_POST['check_username'];
    $sql="SELECT user_login_name FROM users WHERE user_login_name='$user_login_name'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $numRows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
    var_dump($rows);
    if($numRows>0){ // If exists rows
        foreach($rows as $field)
            echo $field." => ";
        echo "<br>";
    }
    else
        echo "Database empty!";
}
```

Also to connect your data you can try:

```
$.ajax({

});
```

Passing variables from php and you can decide if you show data or not from javascript side.

I hope it helps C:

Comment: This is open to SQL injection; have you heard what that does and how to prevent it?

Comment: Is there anyway that the array information will not be echoed as well?

Comment: Well, we can talk about sql security in another post. This question is not about sql injection I guess... Also is not a best practice.